# Available IDE's for Oracle iStore jsp.

Tags: jsp, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

I am working with Oracle Apps, customizing jsp pages for oracle iStore applications.Now, we are using Dreamweaver for viewing and editing jsp pages.The page may be coded with html,scriptlets and styles. I am new to iStore applications and can we use Eclipse as IDE for this jsp pages. Or any other better IDE available for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eclipse IDE for editing the jsp file.

Jdeveloper is the IDE specified by oracle for use in oracle applications.